# Why does Pandas MultiIndex slice require a column placeholder when selecting all values of the first index level?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider this Pandas data frame with a MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2], [False, True, False, True]]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('grp', 'is_even'))

df
             x
grp is_even   
1   False    1
    True     2
2   False    3
    True     4
```

I can select a specific entry - say, `grp == 1 & is_even == True`:

```
df.loc[(1, True)]
x    2
Name: (1, True), dtype: int64
```

And with `slice` or `pd.IndexSlice` notation, I can select a specific value for the **first** index level (`grp == 1`), along with all values of the second level:

```
# with slice()
df.loc[slice(1), slice(None)]
             x
grp is_even   
1   False    1
    True     2

# with pd.IndexSlice
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[1, :]] # note - correct rows selected but grp index level not shown
         x
is_even   
False    1
True     2
```

But when I try to select **all values** of the first index level, and a specific value for the second index level (e.g. `is_even == True`), this syntax pattern fails (KeyError on the second index level's value).

```
df.loc[idx[:, True]] # also throws KeyError with df.loc[(slice(None), slice(True))]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/betterup-example-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
# ...
```

The error trace is long (and reproducible with this code if it's helpful to see it all), but one segment has a couple of comments that hint at where the problem is (in bold):

> ~/anaconda3/envs/betterup-example-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
> 1371         **# we may have a nested tuples indexer here**
> 1372         if self._is_nested_tuple_indexer(tup):
> -> 1373             return self._getitem_nested_tuple(tup)
> 1374
> 1375         **# we maybe be using a tuple to represent multiple dimensions here**

After some experimentation, I found that adding a column placeholder resolves the error. (Doing this also restores the missing first index level in the `IndexSlice` example above.)

```
df.loc[idx[:, True], :]
             x
grp is_even   
1   True     2
2   True     4
```

I also found I can get there with `query`:

```
df.query('is_even == True')
```

So I'm happy I have a fix, but my Pandas-fu isn't strong enough to understand *why* the error happens without including the column placeholder.  If someone can help me grok what's happening here, I'd really appreciate it!

Pandas version: 1.0.5
Python version: 3.6.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idx[:, True]` is actually just a wrapper to create:

```
(slice(None, None, None), True)
```

So when you pass it to slice, this uses the first part for the index and the second for the columns.

By doing `df.loc[idx[:, True], :]` you make it explicit that the columns slicer is `:`

A further demonstration is trying to run `df.loc[idx[:, 'x']]`, which will correctly slice the column `x`.

---

When running `df.loc[slice(1, True), 'x']`,you are not using `1` for the first level and `True` for the second but rather doing:

```
df.loc[1:True, 'x']
```

If you want to get the item at index (1, True) and column x, use:

```
df.loc[(1, True), 'x']

# 2
```

If you want all values of the first level, just the `True` in the second level and column x:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), True), 'x']

grp  is_even
1    True       2
2    True       4
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - if I'm understanding correctly then putting `:` in the first position for `idx` is effectively broadcasting that value across all index levels - is that right?  Either way, I think there's still something I'm missing. Maybe we ignore the IndexSlice wrapper for now, as I get similar problems using `slice`.  For example, `df.loc[slice(1, None), 'x']` works but `df.loc[slice(1, True), 'x']`. In that example, the second position (columns) is defined, but `None` for index level 2 works, `True` doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: `slice(1, None)` is just `slice(1)`. `slice(1, True)` gets items between `1` and `True` in the **same** level (`1:True`). I think you want `(slice(1), slice(True)), 'x'`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks again for the explanation.  Would you consider adding the piece about the broadcasting of : to (None, None), if that is actually what is happening, to your answer?  Just to get a bit more at the "why" of what is happening.